# Is it possible to add a watermark in MapBox vector tiles?

Tags: mapbox, watermark

A client would like to add their URL as a brand/watermark within a MapBox tiled vector layer in MapBox Studio, so that the watermark appears wherever the tiled vector layer is displayed. (One possible use-case is to discourage competitors from stealing that tiled layer in their own maps.)

Is it possible to add a watermark to a tiled layer in MapBox, and ensure that it's visible at least once in every view?

I tried adding a duplicate copy of a polyline dataset as a Symbol Layer, and labelling it with the client's URL using the Text Field option. This works but has the side effect of preventing the labels from appearing on the original copy of the line layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add a single occurrence of a watermark to a map style in Studio in the way that the Mapbox watermark is displayed on a map, but there are alternative approaches to achieve what you are looking to do.

If the underlying goal is to prevent competitors from using a particular map style (and hence an underlying tiled layer), the best approach is to set [scopes](https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/overview/tokens/#scopes) and [URL restrictions](https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/overview/tokens/#url-restrictions) on the Mapbox access tokens being used to access the map style in a public environment. You can find more useful information about [token management](https://docs.mapbox.com/accounts/overview/tokens/) and [access tokens](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/) in general in the Mapbox documentation. This approach could be used in conjunction with adding a branded "watermark" on the client side -- for example, placing a fixed `div` in the corner of a web map loaded with GL JS. Although this watermark obviously isn't included in the style itself, setting a URL restriction on the access token used to load the map would prevent others from accessing the same map with that token on other domains.

You could also experiment with adding a low-opacity [`background-pattern`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-background-background-pattern) to relevant layers in the map style itself. This property could be used to mimic a traditional watermarked effect, where a particular logo is placed on an image at multiple regular intervals.

Comment: thanks again, this is great advice. The security was really a secondary concern, and it's more of a branding / marketing exercise for the client so your other suggestions are probably of more use